# Custom Action in user dropdown

Tags: 2013, javascript, ribbon, sandbox-solution, custom-actions

Im trying to implement a custom action in the logged in user dropdown (when you click 'sp_admin' in the image below).

The custom action should be a text called "Switch user", which when clicked executes a javascript function.

How do I accomplish this? What value should be used in CustomAction location for starters?

[image: Settings dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an Out Of The Box behaviour that must be activated in the Welcome.ascx inside {SharePointRoot}\Template\CONTROLTEMPLATES folder.

Localize this code in Welcome.ascx

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="ID_RequestAccess"
             Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_requestaccess%>"
             Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_requestaccessdescription%>"
             MenuGroupId="100"
             UseShortId="true"
             Sequence="300"
             />
```

Under this code paste this other

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"
                Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>"
                Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>"
                MenuGroupId="100"
                Sequence="100"
                UseShortId="true" />
```

Now, you should have the Sign in as different user option.

Comment: Normal disclaimer: As always, modifying out of the box controls ain't supported and your changes could be overwritten by a future service pack. This works best for development and evaluation environments.

Comment: Yes. is very important what @JamesLove says. You should create a custom control template and extend the ootb ribbon.